# Extracting a SCM project generate a "maven.4684615498" random folder

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn, version-control

When im doing a " Checkout Maven Project from SCM" , my code is put in the path :

WORKSPACE/Maven.454654987/MyProject!
I want to have my project in :

WORKSPACE/MyProject

Is theire a possibility to not have this random folder name ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I checked out the project as a Java project and then I changhed the nature to Maven nature.